# PL sql to find a string in a list

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a problem because in this code I don't know how I can to test if a string is  in a list which isn't initialized .
The code is this :

```
TYPE t1 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767)  index by PLS_INTEGER;
v_t1 t1;

WOUT                       varchar2(80)                :='bbbb';
v_t1(1):='bbbb';

if (WOUT member of v_t1  ) then

....

end if;
```

I don't know how i can write in plsql the condition that wout is inside v_t1 because member is accepted only with lists initialized.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

With the collection declared as you have it there's no simple way to do what you're trying to do except to iterate through the collection to find the element you want:

```
declare 
  TYPE t1 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767)
    index by PLS_INTEGER;

  v_t1    t1;
  WOUT    VARCHAR2(80) := 'zzzz';
  i       NUMBER;
  bFound  BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  v_t1(0)  := 'aaaa';
  v_t1(1)  := 'bbbb';
  v_t1(2)  := 'cccc';
  v_t1(26) := 'zzzz';

  i := v_t1.FIRST;

  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('i=' || i);

    IF v_t1(i) = WOUT THEN
      bFound := TRUE;
      EXIT;
    END IF;

    i := v_t1.NEXT(i);

    IF i IS NULL THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('bFound=' || CASE WHEN bFOUND THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END);
end;
```

HOWEVER - if you change the collection so that it's indexed by the string it contains you can accomplish this task a bit easier by using the EXISTS collection method:

```
declare 
  TYPE T2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767)
    INDEX BY VARCHAR2(32767);

  v_t2    t2;
  WOUT    VARCHAR2(80) := 'zzzz';
  i       NUMBER;
  bFound  BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  v_t2('aaaa') := 'aaaa';
  v_t2('bbbb') := 'bbbb';
  v_t2('cccc') := 'cccc';
  v_t2('zzzz') := 'zzzz';

  bFound := v_t2.EXISTS(WOUT);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('bFound=' || CASE WHEN bFOUND THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END);
END;
```

The documentation on collection methods [can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#i27396).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create special function that checks if such value is inside collection. Something like that:

```
FUNCTION exist_in_collection( p_table t1, p_text VARCHAR2) RETURN boolean
IS
BEGIN
  IF p_table.LAST IS NULL THEN
     RETURN FALSE;
  ELSE
     FOR i IN p_table.FIRST.. p_table.LAST
     LOOP
        IF p_table(i) = p_text  THEN
          RETURN TRUE;
        END IF;
     END LOOP;

     RETURN FALSE;
  END IF;   
END exist_in_collection;
```

if p_table is not initialized LAST is NULL you will get FALSE. And then you can use this function to check whether the string is inside collection:

> IF exist_in_collection(p_table, WOUT) THEN ... END IF;